# Can't boot from disk

Tags: boot

I've just bought a stick to download the latest version of Ubuntu Desktop. I downloaded the program from Ubuntu and it is now on the stick.
I downloaded it and I see both the file and the ISO file. I open the file folder and all files are listed include "Install" I click on that file and a mt86plus comes up....

I am then asked how do you want to open this file, I tried opening it with 7-Zip and nothing...

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "I see both the file and the ISO file"? You must download the relevant ISO file and make a bootable disk based on it. Have a look on [documentation on USB installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a bootable usb media according to [these](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) instructions.

Answer (score -1):

So i had problem booting ubuntu from USB Stick(Flash Drive) too.

- Be sure your flash drive is bootable, you can see how to make a
  bootable flash drive [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
- If you still can't boot from flash drive you must do a bootalbe DVD.
  You can see [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)
  how to do.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)